# ESP-IDF VScode Monitor KeyError: 'IDF_PATH'

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp-idf

I have installed ESP-IDF extension on the Visual studio code on my Windows 10 machine. When I am trying to open the monitor it is throwing the following error

```
C:\Users\femik\Desktop\esp\blink>C:\Users\femik\.espressif\python_env\idf4.1_py3.8_env\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\femik\esp\esp-idf\tools\idf.py -p COM16 monitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\femik\esp\esp-idf\tools\idf.py", line 775, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\femik\esp\esp-idf\tools\idf.py", line 691, in main    
    checks_output = check_environment()
  File "C:\Users\femik\esp\esp-idf\tools\idf.py", line 64, in check_environment
    print_idf_version()
  File "C:\Users\femik\esp\esp-idf\tools\idf.py", line 113, in print_idf_version
    version = idf_version()
  File "C:\Users\femik\esp\esp-idf\tools\idf_py_actions\tools.py", line 55, in idf_version
    "--git-dir=%s" % os.path.join(os.environ["IDF_PATH"], '.git'),
  File "C:\Users\femik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'IDF_PATH'
```

when tried the command `idf.py -p COM16 monitor` is working

Answer (score 1):

Use This Command :

```
cmd.exe /k  C:\Users\dell\esp\esp-idf\export.bat
```

remark :
in my case esp-idf is this root " C:\Users\dell\esp\esp-idf" please ne sure to use the right path